# Blank space on top of the page over materialToolBar

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mg34.png)

I am having this issue that there is blank space over the top app bar which is supposed to be at the top. Anchoring it to the top doesn't help, "android:fitsSystemWindows="true"" as well.

The structure of my file: CoordinatorLayout with MaterialToolBar(problem) - NestedScrollView - CoordinatorLayout with scrollabel content in it

My code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#E0ECDE"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/topAppBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
        app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar"
        app:subtitleTextColor="#205072"
        app:titleCentered="true"
        app:titleTextColor="#205072">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="14dp"
            android:text="text"
            android:textColor="#68B2A0"
            android:textSize="24dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            style="@style/Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon"
            android:backgroundTint="#68B2A0"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_round_arrow_upward_24"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:iconSize="24dp"
            app:iconTint="#E0ECDE"
            app:strokeWidth="2dp"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle"
            app:strokeColor="#68B2A0" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            
            <!--scrollable content-->
            
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>



    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        app:backgroundTint= "#FFFFFF"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:elevation= "8dp">
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:itemIconTint="#CDE0C9"
            android:background="@drawable/background_transparent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_app_bar" />
    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This might be because of NestedScrollView, because on other pages without it there is no issue with top bar.
Any ideas on why this is happenning or how to fix it?

Edit: themes code

```html
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Main" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#205072</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#CDE0C9</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">#329D9C</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#329D9C</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="error_appearance_one" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="error_appearance_two" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/error</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Main.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">#56C596</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Main.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.Main.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="Theme.ThemeOne" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#205072</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">#329D9C</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">#329D9C</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#329D9C</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.ThemeTwo" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#CDE0C9</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">#329D9C</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">#329D9C</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#329D9C</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon">
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="iconPadding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:insetLeft">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:insetRight">0dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Circle" parent="">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: What theme are u using ?

Comment: what do you mean what theme? for what?

Comment: Your app's  main theme

Comment: <style name="Theme.Main" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: can u share your themes.xml file ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that white gap is the status bar. you may have accidentally changed it's color to white which eventually hid all the white icons on the bar making it looks like a white gap.

You have colorPrimaryVariant as white in ThemeOne and ThemeTwo , make sure you are not using these theme as they will make your status bar white.

Comment: such a dumb mistake, that was the issue, thank you so much!